# Capture log files that ended with any number

Tags: linux, files, find, regular-expression

We want to capture all logs that ended with ".log.[any number]

So I create this syntax

```
find .  -type f  -regex '^.log.*[0-9]$' -print

command does not give any output
```

But this doesn't capture the files as the following ( expected results )

```
  controller.log.2018-01-03-01  
  server.log.2017-10-31-03
  server.log.2018-01-23-11
  server.log.2018-04-06-17  
  server.log.2018-07-07-05
  controller.log.2018-01-03-02  
  log-cleaner.log.10           
  server.log.2017-10-31-04 
  server.log.2018-01-23-12  
  server.log.2018-04-06-18 
  server.log.2018-07-07-06
  controller.log.2018-01-03-03 
  log-cleaner.log.2   
  server.log.232.434
```

what is wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: why do we use `^`  and `.` should be escaped

Comment: Why use a regex? `find /var/log -type f -name *.log.*[0-9]` No escaping of dots needed, etc.  If you want to find Logs LOGS and logs, then change the `-name` to `-iname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-regex` (a GNU extension also recognised by some other `find` implementations nowadays but with major differences) is like `-path` except that it uses regexps instead of wildcards. It matches on the whole file path, not just its name.

So `.*\.log.*[0-9]` (no need for `^` or `$` by the way, they're implicit with `find`'s `-regex`)  would match on `./dir/foo.log-3` but also `./foo.logic/file.bz2`, where the `.*` captured `ic/file.bz`.

`-name` matches on the file *name* only, uses wildcards but doesn't have a regexp counterpart. Here, for files whose name contain `.log` and end in a digit, you don't need regexps anyway, `-name '*.foo*[0-9]'`.

You can do the same with regexps though with `-regex '.*\.log[^/]*[0-9]'`, that is making sure the part between `.log` and the final digit doesn't contain any `/` so it matches on the file name only.

With `-regex`, you can go further in specifying the patterns, especially if you enable extended regexps, using `-E` with some BSD's `find` or `-regextype posix-extended` with GNU `find`.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.log([.-][0-9]+)+' # GNU
find -E . -regex '.*\.log([.-][0-9]+)+' # BSD
```

Here matching on `.log` followed by one or more `.<number>` or `-<number>`.

Without `-regextype posix-extended` GNU `find`'s regexps are *emacs* regexps, some sort of hybrid between standard basic regexps and standard extended regexps (supports `+`, but grouping is with `\(...\)` instead of `(...)`).

Without `-E` BSD `find` regexps are standard basic regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
find .  -type f   -regex  ".*\.log\..*[0-9]$"
./server.log.2018-01-23-12
./server.log.2018-07-07-06
./log-cleaner.log.2
./log-cleaner.log.10
./server.log.232.434
./server.log.2018-01-23-11
./server.log.2017-10-31-03
./controller.log.2018-01-03-01
./server.log.2018-04-06-17
./log-cleaner.log.1
./controller.log.2018-01-03-03
./server.log.2018-04-06-18
./controller.log.2018-01-03-02
./server.log.2018-07-07-05
./server.log.2017-10-31-04
```

- we need to escape the `.`

Comment: this syntax not works

Comment: @yeal can you share the error

Comment: it si just print only the file - gc.log.0 , but all other are not printed

Comment: yes I already did it

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Answer (score 0):

If after "log" there's only digits, `.`, and `-`, the following might work as well

```
find .  -type f   -regex  ".*[.]log[-.0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for your files using the following way without recourse to `non-GNU` `find`:

```
find . -type f \
    \( -name '?*.log.[0-9]' -o \
       \( \
           -name '?*.log.[0-9]*[0-9]'  \
         ! -name '?*.log.?*[!0-9.-]*?' \
         ! -name '?*.log.?*[.-][.-]*?' \
       \) \
    \) \
    -print;
```

What this does is do a multi-layered filtering of the filenames caught by it and progressively shrinks the catch and zeroes in on the required. To be precise:

- Right away select any file whose `basename`, i.e., w/o it's path ends in a `.log.single_digit`
- OTW, select those that end in `.log.` `NUM` `anything` `NUM` This will set the trend for the filenames to be caught in the net.
- Out of the above catch, reject those which happen to have a `non number, non dash, or non dot` in the `anything` portion of the filename. Note the trend of beginning and ending with a digit must be honored.
- Now our catch has all those files in which `anything` portion comprises only `digit(s)`, `dot(s)`, and `dash(s)`. The last constraint is that the `dot` or `dash` must not have each as their immediate neighbors to both their left and right.
- P.S. Note that `-name` option looks at the basename portion of the filename only, AND
- `-name` portion operates on the `wildcard` basis and hence they are implicitly anchored, meaning the name matched is full.